Are there infinitely many smooth structures for the manifold with boundary [0,1)?
Consider the $1$-dimensional manifold with boundary $[0,1)$. Let $x \in [0,1)$ be the coordinate on $[0,1)$ induced by $[0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Now define for each $\gamma \in (0,1)$ another coordinate system defined by the transition map $\lambda^{(\gamma)}\circ x^{-1}(x) = x^{\gamma}$. We have, that for each $\gamma \in (0,1)$ the coordinate system $\lambda^{(\gamma)}$ induces homeomorphism from $[0,1)$ on itself.
Now consider in the $\gamma$-coordinate system the function $f^{(\gamma)} \circ \lambda^{\gamma} = \lambda$. This function is smooth on $[0,1)$ in this coordinate system. But if we go now to a $\gamma'$-coordinate system, this function reads $\lambda^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma'}}$ which is not smooth unless $\gamma = n \gamma'$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence it seems, that there are infinitely many smooth structures on $[0,1)$.
Is this true? Am I confusing something?

They are different in the sense that the identity map is not a diffeomorphism. But there are other diffeomorphisms between these smooth manifolds.

And what would be such a diffeomorphism, for example?

$[0,1],[0,1),(0,1)$ and $S^1$ with their standard structures are the only $C^r$-manifolds (with/without boundary) of dimension $1$, where $r$ may be taken to be $0,1,2,\cdots,\infty$. In particular any smooth structure on $[0,1)$ makes it diffeomorphic with one of these, necessarily with $[0,1)$ with its standard structure

Do you have a source for this?
